# KeycloakSession is null for authenticated users

Tags: java, keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api

**I have the below code through which I am trying to get the contents of the KeycloakSession. "KeycloakSession" is null everytime and I am not able to print the contents of it and use some of the attributes
elsewhere.**

```js
@Context
public static KeycloakSession keycloakSession;

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(userDetails.class);

    public static void getSessionAttributes() {

        try {
            if (keycloakSession != null) {
                Map<String, Object> authenticatedUser = keycloakSession.getAttributes();
                for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : authenticatedUser.entrySet()) {
                    String key = entry.getKey();
                    Object value = entry.getValue();
                    System.out.println("Key:" + key);
                }
            
            } else {
                System.out.println("keycloakSession is null");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**However, when I put similar code inside a onEvent method of an event-listener, KeycloakSession is never null and I am able to fetch the session details linked to the currently logged in user, something like this always works :**

```js
public class userDetailsProvider implements EventListenerProvider
{
    
      @Context
    HttpServletRequest request;

    private final KeycloakSession keycloakSession;

    public userDetailsProvider(KeycloakSession keycloakSession)
    {
        this.keycloakSession = keycloakSession;
    }

    @Override
    public void onEvent(Event event)
    {
        
        
            String username=null;
         
            try {
                if (keycloakSession != null) {
                    String authenticatedUser = keycloakSession.getContext().getAuthenticationSession().getAuthenticatedUser().getUsername();
                    System.out.println("authenticatedUser from session:" + authenticatedUser);
                } else if (request.getParameterMap() != null) {
                    Map<String, String[]> requestParameters = request.getParameterMap();
                    for (Map.Entry<String, String[]> entry : requestParameters.entrySet()) {
                        String paramName = entry.getKey();
                        String[] paramValues = entry.getValue();
                        if ("username".equals(paramName)) {
                            username = paramValues[0];
                            System.out.println("Username:" + username);
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Username: Anonymous");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

**How can I get the "keycloakSession" outside event listener code, so that I may fetch its attributes ? I am using keycloak 21, with application acting as OAuth2 client, in which, keycloak is configured as auth-server. Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that KeycloakSession is the object to use in your case.
Indeed, when using EventListenerProvider context, the session is managed by Keycloak.
But outside of this, as you seems to be stateless, you cannot get any information about a current "session".

But, you have different options :

### Option 1 :

Implement a singleton and store attributes..
Make your own SessionManagement system. Which might work but is not recommended. (Duplication of data, ensure data are up to date etc...)

### Option 2 :

Use the keycloak API to get needed informations.

Comment: Is there a way to directly access the API or do I have to use REST Calls?